# How to make notification on message send like Facebook

Tags: php, ajax, facebook

How a notification can be shown after we are receiving a new message like FACEBOOK is displaying without refreshing a page. ( facebook is showing RED color notification after receiving a new message).

Thank You

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are **two ways** out there, **you poll**, or **Comet**.

1. Polling means you ask this question to your server periodically: "is there a new message?" with Ajax. If there is a new message, server returns it or the number of new messages.
2. Or you can implement some kind of Comet. Comet is a technology which contains open connections between client and server. Since there is an open connection, your server can send new information to clients.

After the number of new messages arrived to you, **you can edit your DOM via javascript** to show a red notification whereever you want.

Comment: Thank You @Samet. You introduced me a new technology! This is what i am expecting. Can you suggest me any sources for this.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BOSH    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets You can look these.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use setInterval to periodically check for any new updates and then, if they are found, use ajax to pull in the message.

Comment: Because you are already doing the query, you can just update the content...  No need to do the extra check...

Comment: Yes @Matt : You are correct but my doubt is if millions of request are coming from lot of users for a period of time ( say 5sec ) is it a burden on the database ?

Comment: You need to look at balancing the load on your database. Look at things like the interval, do you really need every 5 seconds when 30 may do; how many users do you have and do you need to look at some sort of enterprise scale solution rather than one server.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use jquery to update the content of a div at a sepecific interval...

```
#idofdivtoupdate
```

as it says.. the id of the div you want to auto update...

setinterval is in miliseconds..  (so 5000 checks every 5 seconds)

```
function updatecontent(){
$('#idofdivtoupdate').load('yourserverscript.php'); 
} 

setInterval("updatecontent()", 5000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If ive understood you correctly you need to look up a technology called AJAX, its a combination of JavaScript and XML which allows the sending and receiving of data behind the scenes ie without needed to refresh the page. Theres plenty of tutorials/information out there about it and its not difficult to get the hang of, hope this helps.