# Isn't facebook using setTimeout() or something like that to load new data dynamically

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, dynamic

I'm trying to work on a dynamic chatting and notification on my site. For example, when you receive a new message on facebook, you don't need to reflesh the page, and it automatically appears the little red spot or the message appears right away when someone send it to you. I wonder whether they are using setTimeout() to execute a function every specific time and then load data to your page

Comment: Not sure but they probably use some kind of listener, doubt they would use such a simple thing

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995/is-there-some-way-to-push-data-from-web-server-to-browser

Comment: @cale_b link names the same technology I found on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624448/how-to-make-notification-on-message-send-like-facebook?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696884/how-to-implement-facebook-like-notification-on-cakephp?rq=1

Comment: @juvian - so this is well documented, and this question isn't really new...

Comment: Yup, doesn't seem he did much research but you never know